# Conditionally Remove a nav menu link if session is active

Tags: plugin-development

I'm developing a plugin, with a login system.

I need to conditionally remove a menu entry from a nav menu on the frontend, if `$_SESSION['member-user']` is set.

For example, I want a 'register' link to only appear if `$_SESSION['member-user']` is not set

I did try to search in codex without success. Thank you!

EDIT:

To explain, the menu is configured from admin of wordpress website. I need to delete the link by my plugin. The menu is not echoed from my plugin, but configured from admin (the admin will use my plugin).

Thank you

NEW EDIT:

The process of my plugin is the following:

In "readme" you will read:

1 - create a page with shortcode [login] inside and connect to a menu voice "User" > "Login"
2 - create a page with shortcode [balance] inside and connect to a menu voice "User > "Balance"

If user is logged (not a wordpress user, login is external), I need to remove that first page "Login" (or "Register", not very important in this case)...

I hope it is more clear now... thank you to all!

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to WordPress, it looks like a standard PHP question for which an `if` statement with the `isset` or `empty` functions as the check would work. WordPress does't use sessions natively either

Comment: Ah! I've edited your question so that it's clearer, and taken it off of hold. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell , but I did make another edit to better explain... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can write like below for WordPress :

```
<?php
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have 2 menus, and show a different menu depending on wether the user is logged in or not, e.g.:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => is_user_logged_in() ? 'logged-in-menu' : 'logged-out-menu'
) );
```

You can swap out the `is_user_logged_in()` call with a check of your own

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the output in your plugin with a conditional like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
  <?php if ( !$_SESSION['member-user'] ) : ?>
    <li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
  <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are developing plugin. You can use following code to add menu links dynamically based on SESSION value

```
function new_nav_menu_items($items) {
if(isset($_SESSION['member-user'])){
    $loginlink = '
    <li class="home"><a href="' .get_page_link('YOUR_LOGIN_PAGE_ID_HERE').'?from='.$post_slug.'">' . __('Login') . '</a></li>
    <li class="home"><a href="' .get_page_link('YOUR_REGISTER_PAGE_ID_HERE').'?from='.$post_slug.'">' . __('Register') . '</a></li>
    ';
    $items = $items . $loginlink;
} else {
    $accountlink = '
    <li class="home"><a href="' .get_page_link('YOUR_MY_ACCOUNT_PAGE_ID_HERE').'?from='.$post_slug.'">' . __('My Account') . '</a></li>
    <li class="home"><a href="' .get_page_link('YOUR_LOGOUT_LINK_HERE').'?from='.$post_slug.'">' . __('Logout') . '</a></li>
    ';
    $items = $items . $accountlink;
}
return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
```